# Pybossa can't export project in UI

Tags: pybossa

I've created a project in Pybossa and I was able to create a task, import task, change task presenter. However as I published it, the UI in many places still says "Draft" and when I want to export I just endup downloading the HTML files of the export page.

I used the template "Geo-coding" dataset and presenter.

We hosted pybossa ourselves with freshDB and is running at v2.8.0

No errors in logs.

The screenshot that shows "Draft" tag and the URL of the broken hyperlink:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with that and you can see some tickets regarding this in the GitHub project.

However, in the meanwhile, you can workaround using the RESTful API to export result.

```
$server/project/$projects_short_name/tasks/export?type=task_run&amp;format=csv
```